# Help Using a MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, switches, basic, switching, powermosfet

I have an N-channel MOSFET, part number IXFH30N50P. I am trying to use it as a switch for a 320V 8100uF capacitor bank. My idea is that I would have a separate, small voltage source, like a battery, to apply the gate voltage so as to avoid simply passing 320v through a button.

I have looked around the web for some info on using these devices, but right as I think I have a grasp, another source confuses me again.

As far as I know, the drain would connect to the positive side of the capacitor bank, the source would connect to the negative side of the capacitor bank, and I need to apply a practical voltage (something around 10 V?) to the gate in order to close the circuit. Is this correct?

Also, how do I use the data sheet to determine the gate voltage required to close the circuit?

Thank You

Edit: Here is a schematic of my current set up, with the MOSFET placed where I think it should go. Would this be a valid setup?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo3kSa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: ARe you sure you want this to short out such a large capacitor?

Comment: Well, sort of. It's going through a coil first, but yeah. Should I use a different method?

Comment: OK you just made it sound like you are shorting out the cap, which would be a lot of current for the poor thing to carry. Otherwise as long as you stay in the safe operating ranger some gate voltage 10 or better but less than 30 over the source voltage should be ok. You will need flyback protection though.

Comment: Over the source voltage? So I would have to put like 330 V to the gate? I feel like that defeats the purpose, because then how would I switch that current on

Comment: You probably don't want your user (you?) pushing a button in this circuit that isn't rated for 400 V anyway. If you want to use a lower-rated button, you'll want to look for a solution that's galvanically isolated to protect your users.

Comment: Well that's why I was looking at using a MOSFET. Is this not something a MOSFET can do? It was my understanding that they are used to control large voltages with a small gate voltage, allowing me to use a button

Comment: They can control higher voltage signals with lower voltage signals, but if they fail they might short the high voltage wire to the low voltage one.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Could a high voktage diode prevent this? I can't find a small enough 400V momentary push button.

Comment: If you want to be sure of isolation, use an optoisolator.

Comment: @nekomatic I don't know of an optoisolator that can handle this kind of current

Comment: @Omniscribble I mean use an optoisolator to supply the MOSFET gate drive! You could also use an isolated DC-DC converter to supply the power to the optoisolator LED via your pushbutton; then the button side of the circuit is completely isolated from the hazardous voltage.

Comment: Oh, huh. That's actually a great idea. I'd need a resistor to keep the receiving end of the optoisolator from drawing too much power, but that would solve a few issues I'm having. I'll get back to you whether this turns out to be practical financially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you stay in the safe operating range,  a gate voltage of 10V or better but less than 30V over the source voltage should be ok. You will need flyback protection though. Of course it also depends on how often you plan on switching it, and what kind of currents you will be maintaining too.

You need to wire it up like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1bKzP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Be careful with that capacitor though. That is a lethal amount of voltage and charge.

**UPDATE**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNJEMe.png)</sup>

Comment: Ok, I think I may have left out some info. My circuit is as follows: eight AA batteries in series power a boost converter, which outputs 320 V DC. That output is connected directly to the capacitor bank, which is 30 parallel 270uF photoflash capacitors. The coil is connected to the capacitors, and some sort of switch is used to bridge the coil and the capacitor bank. So I kind of understand the schematic above, but the voltage source isn't 15 V, it's 320 V. Would I use a separate power source to the gate, or would I need a resistor between the voltage and the gate? Thanks for your patience

Comment: @Omniscribble the 15V shown there is your gate drive voltage only, I did not show how your cap got charges either. Presumably you can drive that from the top of your 8 AAs.

Comment: Ok, so put the drain toward the positive end of the capacitor, the source toward the coil, and run a wire with a diode from the positive end of the battery before the converter to the gate?

Comment: @Omniscribble, Please include your schematic in your post (click "Edit", then Ctrl-M to use the built-in schematic editor). That way people don't have to search through comments to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Right, I'll do that when I get to a computer then. Sorry bout that

Comment: Just added the schematic.

Comment: @Omniscribble see my edit

Comment: Woah, ok, I was a bit off. Thank you so much. And this won't damage the battery?

Comment: @Omniscribble The booster might... And the mosfet might blow up if the current is too high.. but the discharge should not impact the battery. I just added a flyback diode too..

Comment: @Omniscribble adding another diode in the gate line would be a good idea too..just in case

Comment: I'm sorry for all the questions, I just want to make sure I'm safe. If the booster might damage the battery, then what is the purpose of connecting the negative wires across the converter?

Comment: @Omniscribble you need a common ground, don't feed it through the convertor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68684/discussion-between-omniscribble-and-trevor).